# Bad SATA Controller?

Tags: bsod, sata

My PC has now died twice in the past couple of days. It crashed once and said my SSD failed the S.M.A.R.T test. I had a hunch this happened because of the SATA controller, but I went ahead and reformatted a different SSD, used a different SATA cable, reinstalled Windows and just used it minimally to see if it would happen again. Two days later Chrome hung and everything froze, so I did a hard restart and got this same BSOD again.

Long story short I was fixing someone else's HDD for their laptop and had it connected to my PC. Someone accidentally touched the hard drive while it was hanging out and I heard a "tick." I immediately knew ESD could then be a problem. About an hour later I had my first crash. I fixed it a few days later and it worked fine for about two days and it now crashed again.

Is it time for a new motherboard, or does someone else have a different idea on what to test or how to test what might be wrong? [image]

Comment: It could be coincidental, but it could be a motherboard issue - its difficult to tell for sure.   Issues with faulty SATA ports causing data loss are not unprecedented - Indeed there was a major issue about 6 years ago with the SATA controllers on some Intel chipsets.

Comment: @davidgo I agree it could be highly coincidental, but the fact it happened so fast, I think the zapping caused the issue. I built this PC in 2012 and the only problem I had was a PCIe slot that went bad. A bit more hardware info, I have an ASUS P8Z77 PRO-V motherboard with an i7-3770k. I've been wanting to upgrade a few things and now may be the perfect time.

Comment: Your chipset is not the one I as thinking of - but https://www.anandtech.com/show/4142/intel-discovers-bug-in-6series-chipset-begins-recall makes interesting reading - and I wonder if you are having similar issues (but for unrelated reasons - Im not saying "blame a design flaw at Intel")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end result was a zapped SATA controller which kept causing hard drives to do crazy things ranging from BSODs, failing S.M.A.R.T test on boot and long hangups.

I tried to reinstall with three different hard drives, two SSD and one regular hard drive. All of them had the same erratic behavior.

I had already sent the SSD to Samsung for testing explaining that it was failing the S.M.A.R.T test and failing to boot. Before I got the drive back, I had ordered a new motherboard and rebuilt my PC.

When the drive was returned to me from Samsung, all of the S.M.A.R.T tests passed and the drive was in good health. I installed the OS and my programs again and have no problems in the past 8 months.